# xpath_table в postgresql?

Tags: sql, база-данных, xml, postgresql, xpath

Есть таблица mydocs с колонками ( id serial, docform int, content text)
делаю такой запрос

```
SELECT * FROM 
  xpath_table('id','content','mydocs',
              '/tutorial/author|/tutorial/title',
              'true')
  AS t(id int, author text, title text, docform int)
```

выводит id, author и title, в колонке docform выводит 0.
Как вывести в колонке docform цифру, относящуюся к своей записи в дб.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*, m.docform 
  FROM mydocs m
  INNER JOIN LATERAL 
      xpath_table('id','content','mydocs',
                  '/tutorial/author|/tutorial/title',
                  'true')
      AS t(id int, author text, title text) ON m.id = t.id
```

Вот так выводит всё, как я хотел
даже легче, чем я думал